# Activity table in schema builder

Tags: schema-builder

When looking at schema builder we see an object Activity. But when I tried to query it, 'entity type Activity does not support query' error is received. What is the purpose of this table and how is it important?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3):

It's the parent "SObject" type that represents `Task` and `Event`. It appears only in relationship queries, such as:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories) 
FROM Account
```

Of course, this is only a convenience object, because it really represents two distinct objects, and only serves a purpose in queries to collapse both tasks and events into ActivityHistories or OpenActivities.

Answer (score 2):

`Activity` is a kind of a logical object in salesforce. Real concrete types are `Task` and `Event`. You can query on those two types, which are under `Activity` in *Setup > Customize > Activities*. 
For a related note on Salesforce have a look at [here.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

The activity table is really two tables, tasks and events, with similar shared functionality but also differences. So you would really want to query Task or Event, but not Activity.